# Return type for Linq query Joining two tables from a Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, data-access-layer

I'm working on a 3-tier application, on the Data access lay (DAL), I run the queries and return like this

```
public TRAIN getTrainingRecord(int id)
{
        TRAIN ret = null;
        try
        {
            integradboDataContext db = new integradboDataContext(_connectionstring);
            var query = (from us in db.TRAINs
                         where us.id == id select us).FirstOrDefault();
            ret = query;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { misc.logerror(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.Source); }
        return ret;
}
```

then use it like this on the Business Layer (BL)

```
public TrainingRecordFields getTrainingRecord(int id)
{
        TrainingRecordFields ret = null;
        try
        {
            var query_raw = data.getTrainingRecord(id);
            var query = new TrainingRecordFields();
            {
                query.id = Convert.ToInt32(query_raw.id);
                query.staffNo = query_raw.STAFFNO;
                query.courseTitle = query_raw.TITLE;
                query.dateStarted = query_raw.MDATE1.ToString();
                query.dateEnded = query_raw.MDATE2.ToString();
                query.organizers = query_raw.ORGANISE;
                query.venue = query_raw.VENUE;
            };
            ret = query;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { misc.logerror(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.Source); }
        return ret;
}
```

The class name `TrainingRecordFields` is just a POCO class.

Now, I need to join another table to the query so I can retrieve additional two fields. The query should look like this

```
(from us in db.TRAINs
 join st in db.STFREGs on us.STAFFNO equals st.STAFFNO
 where us.id == id select us).FirstOrDefault();
```

In this case, the class `TRAIN` is no longer the appropriate return type because it doesn't have the two fields I need from the other table `STFREGs` .

What is the standard C# way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the two properties as extensions of the POCO. You can do it in the same C# class file or as extension of the class. So, for example:

```
// TrainingRecordFields file
public partial class TrainingRecordFields
{
    ...
}

// TrainingRecordFieldsExt file
public partial class TrainingRecordFields
{
    ...
}
```

I like this approach, because it lets you keep track of extended properties you get from joins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where I need the return type is on the first method with the linq query where the return type is current TRAIN.